# Access main table's values (DISTANCE and SIZE)

Tags: basex

I am storing a vast amount of mathematical formulas as Content MathML in BaseX databases. To speed up lookup with different search algorithms implemented as XQuery expressions I want to access the main table's values especially PRE, DISTANCE and SIZE. The plan is to get rid of all subtrees which provide the wrong amount of the subtree's total nodes (SIZE).

The PRE value is available via the function db:node-pre and working just fine. How can I access the DISTANCE and SIZE values? I could not find a way in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

### The short answer is: you don't, stay with the offered APIs

If you really want that IDs, use the `parent::node()` and `following-sibling::node()[1]` axes and query their pre values. Following equations hold:

- `PRE(.) = PRE(parent) + SIZE(parent)`
- `PRE(following-sibling[1]) = PRE(.) + SIZE(.)`

so you could read those values in constant time by reordering those equations.

### The long answer: dig deep into BaseX internals

You'll touching the core (and probably shouldn't, kittens might die!). Implement a BaseX Java binding to get access to the [`queryContext` variable](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/blob/master/basex-core/src/main/java/org/basex/query/QueryContext.java), holding the [database context `context`](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/blob/master/basex-core/src/main/java/org/basex/core/Context.java), which you can query to get a [`data()` reference](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/blob/master/basex-core/src/main/java/org/basex/core/Context.java#L165):

```
Data data = queryContext.context.data();
```

Once you have the [`Data`](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/blob/master/basex-core/src/main/java/org/basex/data/Data.java) reference, you get access to several functions to query values of the internal data structure:

```
int Data.dist(int pre, int kind)
int Data.size(int pre, int kind)
```

where [`kind` is always `1` for element nodes](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/blob/master/basex-core/src/main/java/org/basex/data/Data.java#L41).

Be brave, and watch your step, you're leaving the safe grounds now!